# Finding the solution to $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given that $(1, -1, 1, 1, 1)^T$ is a solution to $Ax = b$, where 
$A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    -1 & -1 & 2 & -3 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$ and $ b =     \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
3 \\
-3 \\
    \end{pmatrix} $.

I thought the given solution can be found by using the reduced row-echelon form and worked out as follows: 
$$ rref = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

However, i can't seem to deduce the solution of $(1, -1, 1, 1, 1)^T$ from above. Why?

Comment: How did you get a $5 \times 5$ row-reduced matrix from a $4 \times 5 $ matrix?

Comment: What is the question here? You have 4 equations with 5 unknowns, so the solution, if it exists (and it does, as given) is not unique. Maybe the given solution is hidden in the formulas you get as a result of solving the equations?

Comment: First, your “rref” isn’t actually in row-reduced echelon form and second, it has more rows than $A$, so can’t be a reduced form of $A$, even after augmenting it with $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for the solutions for $Ax = b$, so we can look at the augmented matrix [A | b]
$$[A | b] = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    -1 & -1 & 2 & -3 & 1& 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3\\
    1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -1& -3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

which , after row reducing yields 
$$rref \ [A | b] = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1& 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
So now we see that the solution set is given by
$$x=\begin{cases}  
x_1 = 1 - x_2 -x_5 \\
x_3 = 2 - x_5 \\
x_4 = 1 \\
x_2, x_5 \ \ \text{free variables}
\end{cases}$$

Now notice that, because you know that $x_2, x_5$ are free variables, by setting $x_2 = -1$ and $ x_5 = 1$ we would get $x_1= x_3 = x_4 = 1$ , hence a possible solution would be $x= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 &1 &  1\end{bmatrix}^T$

However, if you want to view the general solution in a parametric way, we only have to go a step further. We can write is as

$$x =  \begin{bmatrix}
    1-x_2-x_5\\
    x_2 \\
    2-x_5 \\
    1  \\
    x_5    \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    0 \\
    2 \\
    1  \\
    0    \\
    \end{bmatrix} +  x_2 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -1\\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0  \\
    0    \\
    \end{bmatrix}
+  x_5 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -1\\
    0 \\
    -1 \\
    0  \\
    1    \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
and then in you could simply plug in values for $x_2$ and $x_5$.